# Rep history shows downvote, but no downvote found on the linked answer

Tags: support, reputation, voting

My [SO rep history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder?tab=reputation) today shows a downvote on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896626/switch-statement-for-string-matching-in-javascript/2896642#2896642), and yet the answer doesn't show any downvotes. I've waited a bit and refreshed a few times, thinking it might be some weird caching, but...

Is there something going wrong? I don't care about the -2, of course, but if there's something going wrong with SO's rep/voting system, I figure SE wants to know...

Rep history:

[image: rep history showing downvote]

Answer:

[image: the answer showing vote counts with 162 up and 0 down]

Comment: Bit of a guess but that same question has an "unupvote", I'm guessing you haven't lost the full +10 because of the rep cap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you expand that reputation item in you reputation history, you can see that the −2 are coming from an unupvote:

[image: history expanded showing un-upvote]

While this would normally amount for –10, you received an upvote worth +2 for that answer the previous day which should be due to reputation capping:

[image: previousupvote at +2]

So everything seems to be in order.

Comment: ***Doh!*** What an idiot I am not hitting the expand arrow. Thanks - dumb question, good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Took a look at the history - someone upvoted, downvoted then upvoted again.

Probably a slip of the mouse followed by a corretion.